# how to import and modify react-native package into respective native development tools

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, react-native

I coming into react-native from the web development / javascript side of the world. I have been able to get pretty without having to get into the native side of things, mostly thanks to community developed packages. Having said that I am now at the point where I would like to be able to tweak some elements of the native parts of these packages.

My assumption is that the native portions of these packages are developed in XCode and Android Studio. My question is how do you import a cross-platform reactive package into their respective native development toolsuites?

For example if I wanted to import and modify https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-datetime?

Answer (score 2):

- if you want to edit library for ios, you can navigate to the library root and open ios/*.xcodeproj file in xcode.
- if you want to edit library for android, you can open the android folder that inside the library root in android studio.

Comment: so if you do this, you should be able to build and run the package? to what extent do you develop in android-studio or XCode vs. react-native?

Comment: facing the same issue.. but if I edit Android Java library wont my changes be overwritten next time ill to a clean build? what is the best way to handle native changes if PR from to the creator library is not an option?